# How MATLAB mex files access MATLAB instances?

Tags: matlab, dll, mex

This is the entry point for every mex file:

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]);
```

In fact mex files are windows dll files with mexFunction as the main function.
My question is when the mex function is called, how it can access matlab instance specific data from inside the mex. As an example, consider 'mexPutVariable' function. It's job is 'copy an array from inside MEX-function into the specified workspace (outside mex)'. But how it knows where is 'workspace'. No parameter has passed to mex (like a pointer), containing matlab instance data (caller). mex files know only nlhs, plhs, nrhs, prhs and none of them can help mex files to excavate matlab instance specific data(caller function information).

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is that `"Matlab.exe"` is declaring `mexPutVariable` as an exported function:

```
[Matlab.exe]

int __declspec(dllexport) mexPutVariable(const char* workspace, const char* name, const mxArray* parray)
{
    ...
}
```

It is then very easy to retreive this function from the dll using [`GetModuleHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683199(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`GetProcAddress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
[Module.dll]

// Declare function pointer 
int (*FctnPtr)(const char* workspace, const char* name, const mxArray* parray);

// Retreive the main executable 
HANDLE hExe = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

// Link to exported function in the exe just like you would do for any dll    
FctnPtr mexPutVariable = (FctnPtr)GetProcAddress(hExe, "mexPutVariable");

// Use exported function from the dll
mexPutVariable("Base", "foo", myArray);
```

For compiling the mex file and after looking at `mex.h` file,  `mexPutVariable` is declared as an external function to link with:

```
LIBMWMEX_API_EXTERN_C int mexPutVariable(const char* workspace, const char* name, const mxArray* parray);
```

Which turn to be simply (when compiled as dll side):

```
 extern "C" int mexPutVariable(const char* workspace, const char* name, const mxArray* parray);
```

Comment: Is it a possible answer or a real answer?

Comment: I don't have the source of matlab so it can only be a guess ... anyway without passing pointers to the dll I can't see any other reasonable solution for calling back into the main process.

Comment: As an alternative, maybe in the ".lib" your mex source file is linking with there is an exported function matlab is also calling too in order to initialize `mexPutVariable` etc (i.e. passing simple pointer at initialization time).

Comment: I think that would not change the situation. You are right. I think the only possible answer is what you mentioned in your answer. inside ".lib" there is a references to other dlls. I think in that dlls the strategy you mentioned is performed.

Comment: But if I could decide a way to do so, I would add a parameter called handle to pass MATLAB specific instance data. like:void mexFunction(int handle,int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]); then add a handle to every function that uses MATLAB workspace like: mexPutVariable(int handle,...); [handle is the address of matlab instance data structure]

Comment: It's more "magic" to extend matlab without showing/worrying about the "glue" ;)

Comment: This is one of the drawbacks of using closed source software.